# I am unable to connect with two APIs for python

Tags: python-3.x, finance, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

I would like to connect with the TWS API for python however when I tried there was an error saying unable to connect with TWS and that I need to make sure that the TWS port is open. I am unsure what they mean by this.

This is some of my code:

```
from ib_insync import *
util.startLoop()
ib=IB()
ib.connect("127.001", 7497)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a client ID to the ib connect
Also a valid IP address has three dots, so 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.001

```
from ib_insync import * 
util.startLoop
ib=IB()
ib.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=1)
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked . do you know of any resources where  can learn more about algorithmic trading in python as well as using the ib isync package . thank you